# Core files updated, but getting "No Pending Updates" message

Tags: 7, updating

This is my first time developing for Drupal, and it came time to update the site. I followed all the instructions in the update.txt file by doing the following:

1. backed up files and databases
2. put site in maintenance mode
3. deleted old files and installed new ones
4. ran update.php

The problem I'm running into is that update.php is telling me that there are "No Pending Updates". However, when I take my site out of maintenance mode and flush my cache, I'm still getting messages that I need to install security updates. Is this just a problem with my alerts system, or is there something I'm missing in the update?

Thanks, in advance, for helping a Drupal Noob.

Comment: I'll add this as answer later, but here's what I came up with: Turns out, what I did wrong was not copy the new core files from the modules directory. I assumed that I wouldn't need to copy those (just like the "sites" folder), and I feared losing my installed modules. Turns out, as you probably already know, the core files in the modules folder needs to be updated as well.

Comment: It sounds like you're putting contributed and custom modules in the core modules folder - I hope that's not the case...

Comment: No. It's not the case. I've been uploading zips for modules through the Drupal interface, so they've gone to the right folder. I mistakenly _thought_ they were in the core modules folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is helpful for other beginners:

Turns out, what I did wrong was not copy the new core files from the modules directory. I assumed that I wouldn't need to copy those (just like the "sites" folder), and I feared losing my installed modules. Turns out, as you probably already know, the core files in the modules folder needs to be updated as well.